# Can't I use fscanf() for infinite time?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int n;
    FILE *file;
    printf("We are here to create a file!\n");
    file = fopen("demo.txt", "w+");
    if (file != NULL)
        printf("Succesfully opened!");

    printf("Enter number\n");
    while (scanf("%d", &n)) {
        fprintf(file, "%d", n);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

why `fscanf()` is not working here? Here `scanf` is working properly but `fscanf()` is not responding or working here. Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Comment: There is no call to fscanf in the code you show.  Are you attempting to call fscanf to read from the file which you have opened with mode "w+"?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems:

- the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`
- you do not exit the program if the file cannot be opened. You will have undefined behavior if `fopen` returns `NULL` because you later pass this null pointer to `fprintf`.
- the loop iterates until `scanf()` returns `0`. You should instead iterate while `scanf()` returns `1`. `scanf()` will return `EOF` if it fails at end of file, causing an infinite loop.
- you should probably output a separator after the number in `fprintf()` otherwise all numbers are going to be clumped together forming a long sequence of digits.
- `main()` should return `0` or an error status

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    FILE *file;

    printf("We are here to create a file\n");
    file = fopen("demo.txt", "w");
    if (file != NULL) {
        printf("Successfully opened\n");
    } else {
        printf("Cannot open demo.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter numbers\n");
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        fprintf(file, "%d\n", n);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding your question: *why can't I use `fscanf()` instead of `scanf()`?*

- you can use `fscanf()` as long as you give it a stream pointer opened for reading: if you write `while (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &n) == 1)` the program will behave the same way.
- if you want `fscanf()` to read from `file`, you need to perform a file positioning command between read and write operations, such as `rewind()` of `fseek()`. Yet `fscanf()` will fail if there is no number to read at the current position in the file and since you open `file` with `"w+"` mode, `fopen()` will be truncated it.

You could cause an infinite loop by writing a number to the file, rewinding it to the beginning and re-reading the same number, etc.

Here is some code for illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    FILE *file;

    printf("We are here to create a file\n");
    file = fopen("demo.txt", "w+");
    if (file != NULL) {
        printf("Successfully opened\n");
    } else {
        printf("Cannot open demo.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        fprintf(file, "%d\n", n);
        rewind(file);
        while (fscanf(file, "%d", &n) == 1) {
            printf("read %d from the file\n", n);
            if (n == 0)
                break;
            rewind(file);
            fprintf(file, "%d\n", n >> 1);
            rewind(file);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Interaction:

```
We are here to create a file
Successfully opened
Enter a number: 10
read 10 from the file
read 5 from the file
read 2 from the file
read 1 from the file
read 0 from the file
```

Comment: I have tried to run your given code but it didn't work too. I used codeblocks as IDE

Comment: Actually I am new in learning file. So I couldn't catch what you say at your 5 points at very first line.

Comment: @EvanShareef: which code did you run? I ran both and they work fine at the command line. The first program asks for numbers and stores them into the file `demo.txt`, the second behaves as shown in the interaction.

Comment: @EvanShareef: I tried to be as explicit as possible in my remarks. The corrected version shows corrections for each remark in the list.